# Read variable in csv data set config jmeter

Tags: file, csv, variables, jmeter

My script is created csv file and then read this file in csv data set config. I have a file name and put into a variable (path) and send ${path} in filename input of CSV data set config.
I debug and path variable has value as I want, example (Perf_04.csv) and the file is also created. But Jmeter always shows issue that ${path} does not exist.
Did anyone get the idea for this issue? Seemly that when running Jmeter will be run csv data set config first and it throws an error when can't find this file from the beginning.

Comment: Set the absolute file path rather the relative path.

Comment: My file name is dynamic so i need put value into input filename of csv data set config

Comment: Oh, Your CSV Data Set Config will initialise first in your test plan. Thats the reason.

Comment: But why if i put exactly name or variable from User define variables, this issue is not occur?

Answer (score 1):

As per [JMeter Documentation the execution order](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/test_plan.html#executionorder) of test elements looks like

> 1. Configuration elements
> 2. Pre-Processors
> 3. Timers
> 4. Sampler
> 5. Post-Processors (unless SampleResult is null)
> 6. Assertions (unless SampleResult is null)
> 7. Listeners (unless SampleResult is null)

So your [CSV Data Set Config](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config) is being initialized **before** the csv file is actually being created. As of current JMeter version ([JMeter 5.0](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/what-is-new-jmeter-5)) there is no way of amending this behavior, you can consider consuming data from the CSV file using i.e. [__CSVRead() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__CSVRead) instead.

Comment: how to define end of file if i use __StringFromFile?